# Possible meanings of "ho davvero fame"

Tags: meaning, difference

Can "ho davvero fame" mean both "I am really hungry" ( = I am very hungry) and "I really am hungry" (= I am truly hungry, I am not lying about it) ?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, the adverb ***davvero*** can have the meanings you mentioned in your example. Most of the difference would be made by the tone you pronounce the phrase with.

Inspecting the definition of [davvero](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/davvero/) on Treccani's dictionary you can find:

> **davvéro** avv. [comp. di *da* e *vero*]. – 1. Veramente, in verità, proprio:
>   *intendi d. ritirarti?; mi dispiace d.*; con aggettivi: *bello d., bravo
>   d.; è un libro d. interessante*; talora ironico: *hai fatto bene d.!*;
>   sei d. gentile! Spesso rafforza la negazione: *non voglio d.
>   rimetterci; io non ci vado d.; no davvero.* Usato da solo, nelle
>   risposte esprime conferma: *«Ci sei stato proprio?» «Davvero!».*
>   Interrogando, esprime dubbio o meraviglia per ciò che uno racconta:
>   *davvero?* (cioè: «è proprio così come dici?»). 2. Preceduto da per, e
>   nelle locuz. fare d., dire d. e sim., significa «sul serio»: *se le son
>   date per d.; dici d.?; non scherzo, faccio davvero.*

The former meaning corresponds to the case

> I'm really hungry (= I'm very hungry)

and can also be used as an intensifier.

The latter meaning corresponds to

> I'm really hungry (= I'm truly, seriously hungry and I'm not lying about that)

even if to be more clear you should say

> Ho fame per davvero.

Comment: We can also rephrase "I'm very hungry" as "ho proprio fame".